# Problemas de rutas en linux al generar reporte de base de datos en PDF

Tags: java, mysql, linux, vscode

Tengo un problema con las rutas al querer generar una dirección para crear un archivo en windows es fácil pero como seria en linux si la ruta del disco solo es una diagonal "/" ya intente todas las formas posibles "/home/user" y en la ruta "/Documentos/nombre del arichivo" o "~/home/user" y en la ruta "~/Documentos/nombre del archivo" como lo marca en la terminal.

```
// Asi es como se hace en Windows, pero yo quiero saber como seria escrito la ruta en linux
               
Document documento = new Document();

    String ruta = System.getProperty("user.home");                
    PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(ruta + "/Desktop/Reporte.pdf"));
    documento.open();
```

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar.

Comment: Cual es el problema que tienes al ejecutar? Lo podrias agregar a la pregunta? (el stacktrace de la excepció, asumo).

Comment: Bueno puse un JOptionPane para que muestreal presionar el boton para generar un mensaje al momento de crearse el archivo, pero no me aparece el mensaje y ni el archivo el la ruta, no se si esta bien escrita la ruta donde quiero que vaya el archivo, en el string colo /home/user y en el outputstream la ruta a donde quiero que se guarde, pero no genera nada, no se si esta bien escrito la ruta, el pedazo de codigo que coloque es una muestra como se escribe en windows, pero para lunix no se que me falta.